# Is it still possible to spawn "Uber Diablo"?

Tags: diablo-ii

Not to be confused with the Diablo that appears in Uber Tristram, Uber Diablo was created to soak up duped "Stone of Jordan" rings that were a large problem for a while across servers. The idea was to sell Stone of Jordans to vendors to spawn Uber Diablo on all "Hell" difficulty games for a specific server.

Since this event, plus the "Rust Storm" consumed most of the SoJs, is it still reliably possible to spawn Uber Diablo (and therefore get the coveted "Annihilus" charm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**, though infrequently now. Spawning Uber Diablo is a [world event](http://diablo2.diablowiki.net/World_Event) not related to your specific game, but what happens in your realm. No one knows the Stones of Jordan threshold required to spawn him, but supposedly after selling enough SoJs on Hell difficulty, you'll see the message, "Diablo Walks the Earth." The screen will shake and he'll be nearby in the place of the next SuperUnique.<sup>[1](http://diablo2.diablowiki.net/Uber_Diablo#Locations)</sup> **You can't summon him in single-player without a mod** (e.g., Plug Y).

The hardest part of this process is being on the right realm/server when the event is about to be triggered.<sup>[2](http://diablo2.diablowiki.net/Diablo_Clone_Hunting_Guide)</sup> The `OP DClone` chat channel<sup>[3](http://www.mombu.com/games/diablo-2/t-op-dclone-channel-info-1550878.html#4)</sup> tracks realms attempting the event, and you must hop between games, checking your IP until you're on that realm/server.<sup>[4](http://www.diablowiki.com/Uber_Diablo_(Diablo_II)#How_Uber_Diablo_Spawns)</sup>